# Error getting alerts from compliances Your environment may not have any index with Wazuh's alerts

Tags: elk

I am new in elasticsearch. I have to set up wazuh with elasticsearch cluster. I did all the thing. I have also installed wazuh plugin on the Kibana . Once, I opened the app and clicked on the agent section It is saying =>
Error getting alerts from compliances
Your environment may not have any index with Wazuh's alerts

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to uninstall and install it again. Here you have the official uninstallation guide [Uninstalling Wazuh with Elastic Stack](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/uninstall/elastic-stack.html), and after installing Elastic again with this guide [Unattended installation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/more-installation-alternatives/elastic-stack/all-in-one-deployment/unattended-installation.html)

Remember if you want to preserve your configuration you can backup the files:

```
cp -p /var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf.orig /var/ossec_backup/etc/ossec.conf 
cp -p /var/ossec/etc/local_internal_options.conf /var/ossec_backup /etc/local_internal_options.conf 
cp -p /var/ossec/etc/ /var/ossec_backup/etc/client.keys 
cp -p /var/ossec/queue/rids/ /var/ossec_backup/queue/rids/*
```

Here you have more information about that [Migrating OSSEC agent](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/migrating-from-ossec/ossec-agent.html?highlight=var%20ossec_backup%20etc%20client%20keys)

After that, you have to put the files in their original path again